# Bootstrap Typeahead with Facebook Friends

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have this working with jQuery UI's autocomplete:
[image]
How can I accomplish the same with bootstrap's typeahead?

Answer (score 0):

You could load in your Facebook Graph JSON object in typeahead's source function. You'd have to parse the JSON object Facebook returns and format it into an array of strings for typeahead to display. Visually, you can use custom templates for the results that typeahead shows. I would suggest reading these two links to get you going:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/3682

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2441

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you should take a look at this :

https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead

Have fun !