# How to implement Typeahead JS for Facebook Friends Search?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, typeahead, typeahead.js

I have already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690494/bootstrap-typeahead-with-facebook-friends). But that uses the old Bootstrap Typeahead and I'm now trying to use the Typeahead JS for autocomplete of Facebook friends. Well, what I'm trying to do is fetch the friends list from Facebook and use it to fill up input text fields. I'm fetching the facebook friends list using the following lines of code.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        //alert('login success');
        $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" + access_token, function(result) {
            var friends_list = result;
            alert(friends_list.data[0].name);
        });
    } else {
        //alert('not logged in');
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

This code is in the login page (/). This works perfectly and alert function displays the name correctly. After this, I want it to use with Typeahead JS for which I need to give the JSON Prefetch URL. The console shows 403 error when I try to use the same URL with Typeahead JS that is in another page /login/landing.

I tried to use it in Typeahead JS like this :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.example-countries .typeahead').typeahead({
          name: 'jsonvar_string',
          prefetch: "'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token='+access_token",
          template: ['<p class="repo-language">{{data{{name}}}}</p>', '<p class="repo-name">{{data{{id}}}}</p>'].join(''),
          engine: Hogan
      });
  });
```

It didn't work. So, I tried to parse the Javascript variable to get just the friends' name alone and use the JSON object as ***'local'*** parameter in Typeahead like this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //alert('Hi there');
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        alert('login success');
        $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" + access_token, function(result) {
            var friends_list = result;
            var friends_list_length = Object.keys(friends_list.data).length;
            var jsonvar = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < friends_list_length; i++) {
                jsonvar.push(friends_list.data[i].name);
            }
            jsonvar_string = JSON.stringify(jsonvar);
            localStorage.jsonvalue = jsonvar_string;
            window.location.href = "/login/landing";
        });
    } else {
        alert('not logged in');
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Even that didn't work. My Facebook's API call returns JSON like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "ABCD",
         "id": "1234455"
      },
      {
         "name": "PQRSTV",
         "id": "789456"
      },
      {
         "name": "LKJHMN",
         "id": "456789"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/12343434/friends?access_token=CAAJVBDOfUeQBAadfASDFdfdkdERdfdg8pVgJCMbSwIkWyQ0tIjNwoPPIjni7JeMyMbkeTNmxsKRiUe3q0h74Ngl3Ylue2Oz0XlepxUgZBoASpkSted2WV414ziawNZAHW68vLgCArRyxC8vNPeVmoZAueqnL1COrdSvkSItkVXbYVbueUZAhyBwZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100006343431073"
   }
}
```

Anyway to parse the JSON that I'm receiving to use that directly in Typeahead JS or any other way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must convert the `name` key to `value` ou `tokens`. Typeahead.js just recognizes to autocomplete what is written in these keys.

i had the same problem with Twitter API. it may be helpful: [how to integrate typeahead.js with twitter api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023271/how-to-integrate-typeahead-js-with-twitter-api)