# how to integrate typeahead.js with twitter api

Tags: jquery, twitter, typeahead, typeahead.js

i am trying to use typeahead.js to offer autocomplete from a twitter following users list on a text input, through GET friends/list.

here is my code:

```
$('input.twitter_friend').typeahead({
    name: 'countries',
    prefetch: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json',
    limit: 10,
    template: [
        '<img src="{{profile_image_url}} class="autocomplete_img>',
        '<p class="autocomplete_name">{{name}}</p>',
        '<p class="autocomplete_screen_name">@{{screen_name}}</p>'
    ].join(''),
    engine: Hogan
});
```

this form appears after the person is logged on through OAuth.

and, well, it is not working and not saying any error. i don't understand much from twitter api, so, anyone could please help?

Comment: (1) Please tell us what the error is? In general, if you want help, please provide as much relevant information as possible. Telling us that "there's an error" isn't very useful. (2) You're missing a closing quote after `autocomplete_img`. (3) It seems like the `name` for your data source shouldn't be `countries`, probably a copy-paste from one of the examples?

Comment: One more thing: you probably need to implement a `filter` to transform the result of `list.json` to an array of objects that Typeahead can "digest". Probably something with at least a `value`, probably also with `profile_image_url`, `name` and `screen_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a million tests, i discovered that i can't use `prefetch` directly with Twitter API. firstly, i had to work on the JSON.

as i'm working with PHP, i used Twitteroauth (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth), so i make the connection. you can get the user token and token secret from session or database.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
```

in the Typeahead.js ':

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#twitter_friend').typeahead({
        name: 'friends',
        local: [<?php 
            $cursor = -1;
            while ($cursor != 0) {
                $friends = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json', array('screen_name' => $screenname, 'cursor' => $cursor, 'count' => '200'));
                foreach ($friends->users as $friend) {
                    echo "{'profile_image_url': '".$friend->profile_image_url_https."', ";
                    echo "'name': '".$friend->name."', ";
                    echo "'value': '".$friend->screen_name."', ";
                    echo "'tokens': ['".$friend->screen_name."', '".$friend->name."']}, ";
                }
                $cursor = $friends->next_cursor;
            }
        ?> { }],
        template: [
            '<img src="{{profile_image_url}}" class="autocomplete_img">',
            '<p class="autocomplete_name">{{name}}</p>',
            '<p class="autocomplete_screen_name">@{{value}}</p>'
        ].join(''),
        engine: Hogan
    });
});
```

just explaining what i've done:

```
while ($cursor != 0) {
    $friends = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json', array(
        'screen_name' => $screenname, // you must declare this variable somewhere, i just got it from my site database
        'cursor' => $cursor, 
        'count' => '200' // maximum number of values you can do per request
    ));
```

Twitter API's `GET friends/list` can get up to 200 record per request. so i had to loop till i get all of them, that is, `cursor` equals zero (details here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring)

when a request is made using `cursor = -1`, it gets from the start of the list. in the JSON, a new cursor is given. when the list is over, `cursor` returns 0.

in the loop, you can get any info you want about the user. here i get the user name (`screen_name`), `name` and profile image (`profile_img_url`).

this is where the trick to make Typeahead.js work: you must create a JSON containing key pars for `value` and `tokens`. `value` is the value you want the user enter in the input. `tokens` are the words the user can type to get a tip.

as i'm using Twitteroauth, it gives an array, so i have to write the JSON. there must be other ways to make it through PHP (like `json_encode`), so it must seem a little dirty to advanced programmers.

```
foreach ($friends->users as $friend) {
    echo "{'profile_image_url': '".$friend->profile_image_url_https."', ";
    echo "'name': '".$friend->name."', ";
    echo "'value': '".$friend->screen_name."', ";
    echo "'tokens': ['".$friend->screen_name."', '".$friend->name."']}, ";
}
```

so, if i was following this user, i (my twitter screen name is @fksr86) would get a record printed like this:

```
{
    'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000757205383/cd37c8011226aa6014c29737ac03b42f.png',
    'value' : 'fksr86',
    'tokens': 'fksr86', 'Fuks'
},
```

in the JSON Twitter API offers, there's a field called `next_cursor`, that i request to see if it's 0 or not.

```
$cursor = $friends->next_cursor;
```

and it will keep looping till it gets to 0.

maybe there'd be some errors if a user is following too many people due to API request limits.

hope it helps somebody that faces the same problem as i did.